# How to align text with against an image in a table-LyX

Tags: graphics, lyx, includegraphics, lyx-layouts

I am totally new to LyX and currently using the classic-thesis template. I am using a multi-column table in a float figure , where I am importing two images and a text in 3rd column. But I am unable to align the text against the image. I want to align the text in the middle position, not at the bottom.[image: Sample image can be seen below]. Additionally, why images are going up even I chose the alignment middle in the table settings. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the code of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know the minipages?

<kbd>Insert</kbd> → <kbd>Box</kbd> → <kbd>Frameless</kbd> → (right click on the label) → <kbd>Settings...</kbd> → (settings) → <kbd>OK</kbd>

1. Insert one in the first cell, set it to the desired width and height (said 5 cm and 5 cm), and both alignments to <kbd>Midle</kbd>, then insert the first  image, setting **only the height** of the image to be that of the minipage (i.e., 5 cm).
2. Copy the minipage to the second cell and just change the image name.
3. Copy the minipage to the third cell, remove the image and type "25.03"
4. OK? (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)

Comment: Thank you @Fran for this valuable suggestion.